# Who faces the next ball if the striker is run out at the end of an over?

Tags: rules, cricket

Assume 'A' is playing at striker's end and 'B' is at non striker's end, If 'A' runs for a single run on the last ball of the 5th over and B is run out at the striker's end, who will be on strike on for the 1st ball of the 6th over? 'A' or new batter?

Answer (score 0):

For now, ignore the fact that it is the end of an over. The important law here is [18.11.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/scoring-runs):

> When the striker is dismissed in any of the circumstances in 18.11.1.1 to 18.11.1.8, the not out batter shall return to his/her original end.

18.11.1.1 to 18.11.1.8 are bowled, caught<sup>1</sup>, LBW, stumped, hit wicket, hit the ball twice, obstructing the field (under some circumstances) and when a runner is dismissed (under some circumstances). This list does *not* include run out, so the batters remain at the ends they were when the dismissal occurred.

A is now at the "over 5" non-striker's end, so will face the first ball of the 6th over.

<sup>1. Added to the list as of [1st October 2022](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket/60665829).</sup>